# Carry Weight Glitch in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, after performing the Restoration glitch, I now have over 15 million carry weight.  I do not want this.  I just want normal carry weight, and I have tried everything I can think of.  I waited 24 hours, I don't have any active effects fortifying carry weight, I have unequipped/reequipped all my gear, and restarted the whole game.  Can anyone help me with this?  I am on switch, if that has any bearing on it, and have no access to console commands on this file.

Answer (score 5):

K, I'm gonna look like an idiot answering my own question, but I figured it out.  It seems to be a bug with the Extra Pockets perk in the Pickpocket Skill Tree.  I made it legendary, and as soon as the perk was removed, it was back to normal again.  If anyone is looking to have 15,084,303 carry weight, you can do that apparently, but I am not sure what triggered this.

Comment: Personally I hate worrying about carry weight, but good on you for sleuthing out the solution! Normally this stuff requires the console to undo.

Comment: Note that answering your own question is no way makes you look like an idiot. It shows you're willing to resolve your own question; even if that happened after you asked.